# no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH although it is installed

Tags: gcc, mingw

I have downloaded MINGW together with msys and the gcc compiler in order to run a program. In the MINGW console window, from within the directory of the program I want to run, I enter `./configure` and some of the lines that come up are:

```
checking for gcc... no

checking for cc... no

checking for cl.ex... no

configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

I checked in the regular windows command prompt window whether the gcc compiler exists by typing

```
gcc --version
```

From within the same directory that I did `./configure` mentioned above. I can see that the compiler does exist since it tells me the version, Copyright and that there is NO warranty.

So how can I locate this GCC compiler? Why is it not in my MinGW path?

Answer (score 5):

Fresh install.

1) exist only file fstab.sample - rename it to fstab (D:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab)

2) entries in the file not changed (my
        install location d:\mingw) - edit file

```
#Win32_Path             Mount_Point
d:/mingw                /mingw
#d:/ActiveState/perl    /perl
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i had the same error because the postinstall script cant interpret the \ so i ended up with c:mingw which didnt work

Answer (score 3):

this is just a quess: make sure your `fstab` file usually located in `msys\1.0\etc` has a correct entry `/mingw` with the full path of your mingw installation

Answer (score -1):

The `./configure` script is a shell script. You can try to run it as `sh -xv configure`, that will make sh print all commands it executes in the script. This will most likely give some hint on why it does not find your installed gcc binary.

Alternatively you can edit the configure script and insert `set -xv` right before it starts checking for a compiler to reduce the amount of noise.

Answer (score -1):

Install support package on centos

```
# rpm -qa | grep gcc
# yum install gcc glibc glibc-common gd gd-devel
```